# Why did my event subscriber suddenly stop working and how can I debug it?

Tags: 8, commerce, event-subscribers

I've been working on a module in which I'm subscribing to commerce_order.place.post_transition event. However, it suddenly stopped working. Any ideas how I can debug it? I tried Xdebug but it won't even step in.

PS: Just to be clear, I'm talking about this stage:

[image: post_transition]

Below is my code:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\aydinlik\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
use Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductVariation;
use Drupal\state_machine\Event\WorkflowTransitionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

/**
 * Assigns the proper subscription when an order is placed.
 */
class OrderPaySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  /**
   * Current user account.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface
   */
  protected $current_user;

  /**
   * The entity type manager
   * 
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface
   */
  protected $entity_type_manager;

  /**
   * NodeAccessSubscriber constructor.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $this->current_user
   *   Current user account.
   */
  public function __construct(AccountInterface $current_user, EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager) {
    $this->current_user = $this->current_user;
    $this->entity_type_manager = $entity_type_manager;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events = ['commerce_order.place.post_transition' => ['addSubscription', -100]];
    $events = ['commerce_order.place.pre_transition' => ['removeSubscription', -100]];
    return $events;
  }

  /**
   * Adds subscription upon successful payment.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\state_machine\Event\WorkflowTransitionEvent $event
   *   The event we subscribed to.
   */
  public function addSubscription(WorkflowTransitionEvent $event) {
    $dateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',date('Y-m-d'));
    $today = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
    $this->current_user = User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
    /** @var \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderInterface $order */
    $order = $event->getEntity();
    $order_items = $order->getItems();
    $order_item = reset($order_items);
    $product_variation = $order_item->getPurchasedEntity();
    $sku = $product_variation->getSku();
    $from = ["aylik", "yillik", "-"];
    $to = ["Aylık", "Yıllık", " "];
    $name = ucwords(str_replace($from, $to, $sku));
    $epaper_subscription = $this->entity_type_manager->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadByProperties(['name' => 'E-Gazete Aboneliği']);
    $subscription_duration = $this->entity_type_manager->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadByProperties(['name' => $name]);
    $this->current_user->field_abonelik_suresi[0] = ['target_id' => reset($subscription_duration)->id()];
    switch ($sku) {
        case 'aylik-abonelik':
            if (!empty($this->current_user->field_abonelik_turu)) {
              unset($this->current_user->field_abonelik_turu);
            }
            $this->current_user->field_abonelik_baslangic_tarihi->value = $today;
            $this->current_user->field_abonelik_bitis_tarihi->value = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month'));
            $this->current_user->field_abonelik_turu[] = ['target_id' => reset($epaper_subscription)->id()];
            $this->current_user->save();
            break;
        case '3-aylik-abonelik':
            if (!empty($this->current_user->field_abonelik_turu)) {
              unset($this->current_user->field_abonelik_turu);
            }
            $this->current_user->field_abonelik_baslangic_tarihi->value = $today;
            $this->current_user->field_abonelik_bitis_tarihi->value = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 months'));
            $this->current_user->field_abonelik_turu[] = ['target_id' => reset($epaper_subscription)->id()];
            $this->current_user->save();
            break;
        case '6-aylik-abonelik':
            if (!empty($this->current_user->field_abonelik_turu)) {
              unset($this->current_user->field_abonelik_turu);
            }
            $this->current_user->field_abonelik_baslangic_tarihi->value = $today;
            $this->current_user->field_abonelik_bitis_tarihi->value = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+6 months'));
            $this->current_user->field_abonelik_turu[] = ['target_id' => reset($epaper_subscription)->id()];
            $this->current_user->save();
            break;
        case 'yillik-abonelik':
            if (!empty($this->current_user->field_abonelik_turu)) {
              unset($this->current_user->field_abonelik_turu);
            }
            $this->current_user->field_abonelik_baslangic_tarihi->value = $today;
            $this->current_user->field_abonelik_bitis_tarihi->value = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 year'));
            $earchive_subscription = $this->entity_type_manager->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadByProperties(['name' => 'E-Arşiv Aboneliği']);
            $this->current_user->field_abonelik_turu[] = ['target_id' => reset($epaper_subscription)->id()];
            $this->current_user->field_abonelik_turu[] = ['target_id' => reset($earchive_subscription)->id()];
            $this->current_user->save();
        default:
            # code...
            break;
    }
  }

  /*
   * Removes subscription upon pending payment.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\state_machine\Event\WorkflowTransitionEvent $event
   *   The event we subscribed to.
   */
  public function removeSubscription(WorkflowTransitionEvent $event) {
    $this->current_user = User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
    if ($this->current_user->hasRole('abone')) {
      $this->current_user->removeRole('abone');
      $this->current_user->save();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Because this is a basic PHP error I don't think it's going to be useful to future visitors and as such I'm closing it. It also wouldn't have "suddenly" stopped working, it would've stopped working when you added the incorrect code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the array each time in getSubscribedEvents instead of adding entries to it.

It should look more like this:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events = [];
    $events['commerce_order.place.post_transition'] = ['addSubscription', -100];
    $events['commerce_order.place.pre_transition'] = ['removeSubscription', -100];
    return $events;
  }
```

Or

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return [
        'commerce_order.place.post_transition' => ['addSubscription', -100],
        'commerce_order.place.pre_transition' => ['removeSubscription', -100],
    ];
  }
```

Check https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-kernel%21EventListener%21AbstractSessionListener.php/function/AbstractSessionListener%3A%3AgetSubscribedEvents/9.0.x for an example.